# How replace many words with other many words in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find and Replace several several different values all at once](https://superuser.com/questions/211011/find-and-replace-several-several-different-values-all-at-once)

to find multiple words i use **|** 
But  how regex must i use to replace words with many words?
Look here please:

[image]

Comment: Why not just do this with multiple search and replaces?

Comment: A command line utility like `awk` or `sed` or a more unix-like editor like `vim` could do this more easily.

Comment: Sorry guys..but i don't know how use awk and sed. In N++ i have problems to replace ? or () simbols when i have set regex mode..but sometimes i must replace with this simbols..Where is Multiple search and replace? Is a plugin?

Comment: @soandos because that takes considerable longer.

Comment: i'm using windows now and awk does not want to work..Sed seems to work from CMD. What is the command?

Comment: This command (example) works: sed -e "s/zxc/??''*/" -e "s/Text1/www.google.com/"<xxx.txt>yyy.txt  but sed have a replacement character limit (not more 20000) and how can replace / character? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use the normal find/replace function without regex. Do that multiple times for each word-pair you want to replace. If you have to apply this to multiple files, you can record a macro with notepad++.