# Mass search and replace (Not many files, many instances)

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, text-editing

Im doing a project at university where i need to replace the names of people in a chat log we have.

The problem is, i have over 900 unique names i need to replace, and manually doing so would take a lot of time, time i do not have. I have the names extracted and a list of the replacement names, i just need a smart way of mass replacing them. Again, this is not replacing in many different files, its replacing many different things in the same document.

I've been working in Notepad++ trying to do this, but cant seem to find the answer.

Edit: I have looked earlier at the answer provided in [Find and Replace several several different values all at once](https://superuser.com/questions/211011) however as mentioned its 900 unique names, and creating a script described there would also be very time consuming. The person is asking for 2 instances of find and replace, i need over 900

Comment: "creating a script described there would also be very time consuming."  More time consuming then doing them manually one at a time?  To me, it's still a duplicate, if you'd like more/different/newer answers feel free to place a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: Provided that it's not critical how long it takes to perform the updates, your best bet is to use a command-line batch script which runs through each of the substitutions and performs each in turn on the file list. Note that, however you do it, there is a generic problem that any replacements you make may be subsequently updated by a later entry in the substitution list, though this is not insoluble. My tool of choice would be `sed`, native to Linux, and ported to OSX and Windows.