# Replace Multiple Instances of Same Line with Only One Instance?

Tags: notepad++, regex, logging, text-editing

The title says it, really. Basically I am trying to condense an enormous log file.

Notepad++ and Regex (I know a small bit) can delete these repetitive lines, but the problem is, I don't want them all deleted. I want one instance to remain in order to preserve the structure/order of the log messages.

I've googled many an answer but I only seem to get results like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/211011/find-and-replace-several-several-different-values-all-at-once). The problem being that I am not just trying to replace or exclude lines.

At this point I'd guess Regex is more likely to hold an answer, but I'm still at that stage where I don't know what tools are available.

Edit:

Example of a messages that I have thousands of, but only need to see one of:
(I see tons of these, because every scsi device wants to chip in its own message. I only need to see that it's happening, not that it's happening to each of them).

`multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000badf6800005dfe5a8cd2cd: sdie - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000badf6800005def5a8cd273: sdgq - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000badf6800005df05a8cd27b: sdeq - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000bae10c00005df55a8cd2ec: sdgw - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000bae10c00005df05a8cd2c2: sdfk - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000bae10c00005dec5a8cd2a3: sdgm - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
multipathd[4893]: 3600a098000badf6800005df35a8cd292: sdfo - rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence`

But I want to see just

`rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence`

Comment: `The title says it, really.` Except that the title is apparently misleading. The lines you've shown there are not "the same line." They're unique lines, with the last X number of characters/words the same. You might get a useable answer if you identified exactly which parts of the line need to be checked, and which parts can be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple instances are consecutive, you can do:

**Update according to new request:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^-]+- )(.+)(?:\R(?1)\2)+`
- Replace with: `$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (         : start group 1
    [^-]+-  : 1 or more NOT dash,then a dash and a space
  )         : end group 1
  (         : start group 2
    .+      : 1 or more any character
  )         : end group 2
  (?:       : start non capture group 
    \R      : any kind of linebreak
    (?1)    : same pattern than group 1 (ie. "[^-]+- ")
    \2      : backreference to group 2
  )+        : end non capture group, must appears 1 or more times.
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      : content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence
```

---

If the multiples instances are not consecutive, you'd better to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Here is a perl one-liner that does the job:

```
perl -aE 'chomp;(undef,$x)=split(/-/,$_);next if exists $s{$x};$s{$x}=1;say$x' inputfile
```

Comment: @LeeLemur: Yes, you can.

Comment: Could you provide them with example text? Neither has worked for me, and I have fiddled with it quite a bit.

Comment: @LeeLemur: Edit your question and add some lines extracted from your file and expected result.

Comment: I have done so now

Comment: @LeeLemur: But, your lines aren't identical. What are the rules to delete unwanted lines?

Comment: Sorry, I just use the part that IS identical , e.g. "rdac checker reports path is down". I've updated my post now to reflect that

Comment: So you want to lose all lines that end with `rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence`, and in their place see just that phrase, once? In that case, change @Toto's search text to `^.*(rdac checker reports path is down: ctlr is in startup sequence)(?:\R.*\1)+` and you're set. For this one error message, at least.